# I'm using mock for tests using nunit but it doesn't enter the method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, nunit

I am testing my viewModel which contains a method that comes from a dependency injection, but does not enter the method, I honestly do not know what I am doing wrong.

my test.

```
    [TestCase("5")]
    [TestCase("10")]
    [TestCase("-1")]
    [TestCase("0")]
    [TestCase("100")]
    //[TearDown]
    [Test]
    public async Task Deve_Obter_A_Lista_De_Herois_Dado_A_Quantidade_Menor_Ou_Igual_A_100_E_Maior_Que_Zero(string quantidadeHerois)
    {
        //Arrang
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IHeroes>();
        ListHeroesViewViewModel listHeroesViewViewModel = new ListHeroesViewViewModel(null, mockRepo.Object);


        //action 
        await listHeroesViewViewModel.GetHeroes(quantidadeHerois);

        //assert 
        if(quantidadeHerois.Equals("5"))
            Assert.AreEqual(5, listHeroesViewViewModel.Herois.Count);
        else if (quantidadeHerois.Equals("10"))
            Assert.AreEqual(10, listHeroesViewViewModel.Herois.Count);
        else
            Assert.AreEqual(100, listHeroesViewViewModel.Herois.Count);
    }
```

my viewmodel

```
public async Task GetHeroes(string limit)
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            ///
            ////in this point it does not enter the method and returns null////
            ///
            var heroes = await _heroes.GetHeroes(limit);
            if (heroes.data != null)
                Herois = new ObservableCollection<Result>(heroes.data.results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Atenção", $"Error:{ex.Message}", "Ok");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

constructor viewModel

```
public ListHeroesViewViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IHeroes heroes) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigation = navigationService;
         //
         ///here he receives the dependency caused by mock.object
         //
        _heroes = heroes;
        Title = "Heroes";
    }
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, thank you for understanding this is my first test

Comment: You are not setting up the  `GetHeroes` method. And if this is your first test I suggest you read a bit more about mocking. It looks like you are using Moq so, start here: https://github.com/moq/moq4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a mock will return default values, which means for class types you get `null`.

If you want to return something you need to set it up.

Here is an example of a setup that is saying whenever something calls method `GetHeroes` return `new Hero()`.

```
var mockRepo = new Mock<IHeroes>();
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetHeroes(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new Hero());
```

This is a simple setup, you can make it as complex as you want.

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) on how mocking works.